# MySQL's Query Optimizer's take on disk access time

Tags: mysql, database, performance, optimization, query-optimization

I don't have a ton of background with MySQL, and I was wondering of anyone can give me some insight into MySQL's query optimizer and the impact on the cost of disk accesses in determining a query plan for query execution.
I'm interested in whether any statistics collected on disk access times can play an impact on the query execution plan for a fixed set of queries. In particular, when running the same set of queries on the same database image that resides on different drives with varying performance. (note that from MySQL's point of view, this is the same database; the data directory simply resides on different drives that get switched "under" MySQL without it knowing). Could this change in observed disk performance potentially impact the query plan decisions the query optimizer makes at runtime?
I expect that there are many other things more related to SQL itself that the optimizer could do before taking disk accesses into account, but some of you have a lot more experience in dealing with the query optimizer than me.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Unfortunately I have not source to confirm it but I'm almost sure that such stats are not gathered by MySQL. As far as I remember there was post at mysqlperformanceblog.com about outdated approach of MySQL optimizer to SSD drives (they mentioned that costs of random I/O write/read are hardcoded in MySQL source).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about the optimization for pyhsical I/O access in MySQL.
The query optimizer, however, would try to minimize the requisite I/Os(say, the number of blocks) on which queries execute.

The gap of speed between memory and secondary I/O system is so huge that keeping effective cache in memory is the key issue of performance in most of relational database systems.

The query plan, therefore, should keep the requisite I/Os as less as possible for a query however quick the device is.

`<Query Result> <--[Logical I/O]-- <Main Memory> <--[Physical I/O]-- <Secondary I/O System>`

Comment: Well, the query optimizer still needs a lot of assumptions about disc I/O. At least the old rule "if it seems that more than 1/3 of the rows are hit by the where-clause, don't use index, instead do a full table scan" is based on "x blocks of sequential read are faster than y blocks of random access". I am quite sure that also other parts of the query plan should differ.